# Push Unreal project to Github using Gitbash/LFS

Tags: git, github, git-bash, unreal-engine4

I've already tried several of the solutions given to similar questions on here and so far none have worked. The error messages just change occasionally.

I have a team Github repo called WW001-Main and an unreal folder on my pc with the same name which contains all of my Unreal project files. I want to push a copy of that project folder onto the Github repo so the rest of our team can work on it too. The Github repo has a blank readme file, but nothing else (the readme file I'm happy to just copy over).

I've installed LFS, added a .gitignore and .gitattributes and they all seem to work ok now.

The files are now staged to be committed.

I'm then doing:

```
    $ git remote add origin (url of the Github repo)
```

Which gives me:

```
    error: remote origin already exists
```

Then I do:

```
    $git push -u origin master
```

Which gives me the following:

```
    $ git push -u origin master
    Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    remote:
    remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
    remote:      https://github.com/(organisation name)/(repo name)/pull/new/master
    remote:
    To (url of the Girhub repo)
     * [new branch]      master -> master
    Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

When I go to the url given it sends me to https://github.com/(organisation name)/(repo name)/compare/master and says there isn't anything to compare.

When I do 'git status' in Gitbash is shows all the files as still staged to be committed.

The Github repo is still empty. What am I doing wrong here? I've been trying to get this to work for almost three weeks now, as it's a huge bottleneck for our team.

Comment: Have you run `git commit`? Note that your `git remote add` is giving you an error because you already have a remote named `origin`, perhaps from running `git remote add` earlier. While Git-LFS adds its own wrinkles (LFS is a set of wrapper scripts that add features that keep the larger files *out* of Git entirely), your issues here at this point are basic Git stuff, that should be covered in any good Git book.

Comment: I don't know of many *good* Git books at this point, but there's a free one [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) that's not bad at all (many of the online Git tutorials are terrible, so this is a huge step up :-) ).